# Battery discharging with new alternator

Tags: chevrolet, alternator, cobalt

2007 Chevy Cobalt

So I recently replaced my alternator, at first it was working fine, the socket meter I have showed a consistent 14.5V reading, but after turning it off and later in the day start driving again, my car died out on me again and it was reading at around 10.5V. After checking the grounding cable and the 50 AMP fuse in the back and getting rid of some of the corrosion, it starts like normal and stays at 14.5-14.7V, but I'm worried this will happen again. Does anyone know how I should diagnose this if it occurs again?

Update: Turns out that when I start it and it's idling, the alternator is working fine and it's at 14V, but the moment I start driving that's when the voltage drops and the battery starts getting discharged.

Update 2: So I decided to take your recommendations and took the alternator to get tested, turns out it was fine, also got the battery tested. Both came out good and I then learned about the fusible link, and turned out that the nut holding down the wire connecting the alternator to the battery at the starter had come loose and haven't had any issues after I tightened it back up. Thank you guys for the advice that was given.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My first thought ... take the alternator back and have them load test it at the place you bought it from. Wouldn't be the first time a new or remanufactured alternator was bad right out the box.

Comment: Rather than getting rid of *some* or the corrosion, get rid of *all* the corrosion on battery cables and terminals. Disconnect, clean, and re-assemble to correct tightness.

Comment: I'll go ahead and get the alternator tested at where I bought it just to make sure